# Standard name of field label

Tags: standard-objects

I want to replace the standard name of field label to my required. Is it possible eg: I want to change Shipping Address in Account to Company address. Can anyone guide me how can I achieve it.

Comment: In a Visualforce page or a standard page?

Comment: On standard page page so that I can use it on VF page too.

Comment: whats wrong with Ruchika's answer? she pointed in correct direction to change labels universally.

Comment: @AmitBangad I am not mentioning the tab name. I need to change the name of the fields of account. eg : Name to Company Name. I hope the answer is pointing to change the label of the object and tab label only.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Rename Tabs and Labels" in Setup and select "Account" . From there you can rename the fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- From Setup, click **Customize | Tab Names and Labels | Rename Tabs and Labels.**
- Select your **default language** from the Select Language drop-down list at the top of the page.
- Click **Edit** next to the object on which field is present (Account)
- Then click **Next**
- Enter your labels for the standard field labels and other user
  interface elements. Be sure to enter both a singular and plural form
  for each label that requires it. Select Starts with a vowel sound for
  labels that start with a vowel.
- Click **Save**